# Adding integer to ArrayList adds -1 not value

Tags: java, arraylist

When I add a integer to an arraylist it is adding the value of `-1` and not the value such as `349823`. I am calling a counter from an object named "c". So my syntax is `nameofList.add(c.instructioncounter);`

Does any one know what would be wrong? As requested this is my whole class, it is a lot. I am trying to add all the counter values to the arraylist and then pass the array to a method which would then count the standard deviation.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthSeparatorUI;

public class Comparator extends InstrumentedSorter {

    static int count = 1000;

    static float selectionIC = 0;static float selectionE = 0;static float insertionIC = 0;
    static float insertionE = 0;static float bubbleIC = 0;static float bubbleE = 0;static float quickIC = 0;
    static float quickE = 0;static float rquickIC = 0;static float rquickE = 0;static float mergeIC = 0;static float mergeE = 0;

    static ArrayList<Integer> saIC = new ArrayList<Integer>(); static ArrayList<Float> saE = new ArrayList<Float>();
    static ArrayList<Integer> maIC = new ArrayList<Integer>(); static ArrayList<Float> maE = new ArrayList<Float>();
    static ArrayList<Integer> baIC = new ArrayList<Integer>(); static ArrayList<Float> baE = new ArrayList<Float>();
    static ArrayList<Integer> iaIC = new ArrayList<Integer>(); static ArrayList<Float> iaE = new ArrayList<Float>();
    static ArrayList<Integer> qaIC = new ArrayList<Integer>(); static ArrayList<Float> qaE = new ArrayList<Float>();
    static ArrayList<Integer> raqIC = new ArrayList<Integer>(); static ArrayList<Float> raqE = new ArrayList<Float>();  


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Comparator c = new Comparator();
        for (int size = 1000; size <= 10000; size += 1000) {
            for (int round = 1; round <= 10; round++) {
                int[] randomArray = c.createRandomArray(size);
                for (int iter = 1; iter <= 20; iter++) {
                    // clone randomArray for selection sort
                    int[] a = randomArray.clone();
                    c.resetInstructionCounter();
                    c.timer.start();
                    c.selectionSort(a);
                    c.timer.end();
                    saIC.add(c.getInstructionCounter());
                    selectionIC += c.instructionCounter;
                    saE.add((float) c.timer.getTotalTime());
                    selectionE += c.timer.getTotalTime();

                    // clone randomArray for bubble sort
                    int[] b = randomArray.clone();
                    c.resetInstructionCounter();
                    c.timer.start();
                    c.bubbleSort(b);
                    c.timer.end();
                    bubbleIC += c.instructionCounter;
                    baIC.add(c.instructionCounter);
                    baE.add((float) c.timer.getTotalTime());
                    bubbleE += c.timer.getTotalTime();

                    // clone randomArray for insertion sort
                    int[] d = randomArray.clone();
                    c.resetInstructionCounter();
                    c.timer.start();
                    c.insertionsort(d);
                    c.timer.end();
                    iaIC.add(c.instructionCounter);
                    insertionIC += c.instructionCounter;
                    iaE.add((float) c.timer.getTotalTime());
                    insertionE += c.timer.getTotalTime();

                    // clone randomArray for quick sort
                    int[] e = randomArray.clone();
                    c.resetInstructionCounter();
                    c.timer.start();
                    c.quickSort(e);
                    c.timer.end();
                    qaIC.add(c.instructionCounter);
                    quickIC += c.instructionCounter;
                    qaE.add((float) c.timer.getTotalTime());
                    quickE += c.timer.getTotalTime();

                    // clone randomArray for randomized quick sort
                    int[] f = randomArray.clone();
                    c.resetInstructionCounter();
                    c.timer.start();
                    c.randomizedQuickSort(f);
                    c.timer.end();
                    raqIC.add(c.instructionCounter);
                    rquickIC += c.instructionCounter;
                    raqE.add((float) c.timer.getTotalTime());
                    rquickE += c.timer.getTotalTime();

                    // clone randomArray for merge sort
                    int[] g = randomArray.clone();
                    c.resetInstructionCounter();
                    c.timer.start();
                    c.mergeSort(g);
                    c.timer.end();
                    maIC.add(c.instructionCounter);
                    mergeIC += c.instructionCounter;
                    maE.add((float) c.timer.getTotalTime());
                    mergeE += c.timer.getTotalTime();

                }
            }

            average(selectionIC);average(bubbleIC);average(rquickIC);average(insertionIC);average(quickIC);average(mergeIC);
            average(selectionE);average(bubbleE);average(rquickE);average(insertionE);average(quickE);average(mergeE);
            print();
            maE.clear();maIC.clear();raqE.clear();raqIC.clear();baE.clear();baIC.clear();iaE.clear();iaIC.clear();qaE.clear();
            qaIC.clear();saE.clear();saIC.clear();

        }

    }
    public static void print(){

        System.out.printf("┌────────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐\n");
        System.out.printf("│                    │                              Array Size = " +count+"                              │\n");
        System.out.printf("├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────┤\n");
        System.out.printf("│ Sorting Algorithm  │         instruction counter          │               run time               │\n");
        System.out.printf("├────────────────────┼─────────────────┬────────────────────┼─────────────────┬────────────────────┤\n");
        System.out.printf("│   Selection Sort   │%17.2f|%20.2f│%17.2f│%20.2f│\n", selectionIC, sdi(saIC), selectionE, sdl(saE));
        System.out.printf("├────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────────────┤\n");
        System.out.printf("│    Bubble Sort     │%17.2f│%20.2f│%17.2f│%20.2f│\n", bubbleIC, sdi(baIC), bubbleE, sdl(baE));
        System.out.printf("├────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────────────┤\n");
        System.out.printf("│     Merge Sort     │%17.2f│%20.2f│%17.2f│%20.2f│\n", mergeIC, sdi(maIC), mergeE, sdl(maE));
        System.out.printf("├────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────────────┤\n");
        System.out.printf("│   Insertion Sort   │%17.2f│%20.2f│%17.2f│%20.2f│\n", insertionIC, sdi(iaIC), insertionE, sdl(iaE));
        System.out.printf("├────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────────────┤\n");
        System.out.printf("│     Quick Sort     │%17.2f│%20.2f│%17.2f│%20.2f│\n", quickIC, sdi(qaIC), quickE, sdl(qaE));
        System.out.printf("├────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────────────┤\n");
        System.out.printf("│ Random Quick Sort  │%17.2f│%20.2f│%17.2f│%20.2f│\n", rquickIC, sdi(raqIC), rquickE, sdl(raqE));
        System.out.printf("└────────────────────┴─────────────────┴────────────────────┴─────────────────┴────────────────────┘\n\n\n");

        count += 1000;
    }
    public static float average (float variable){
        variable = variable/2000;
        return variable;
    }

    public static float sdl (ArrayList<Float> name){
        float total = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < name.size(); i++) {
            total += name.indexOf(i);
        }
        total = total / name.size();
        float deviation = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < name.size(); i++){
            deviation += (Math.pow((name.indexOf(i)-total),2));
        }
        deviation /= name.size();
        deviation = (float) Math.pow(deviation, 2);

        return deviation;
    }

    public static float sdi(ArrayList<Integer> name){
        int total = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < name.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(name.indexOf(i));
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < name.size(); i++) {
            total += name.indexOf(i);
        }
        total = total / name.size();

        int deviation = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < name.size(); i++){
            deviation += (Math.pow((name.indexOf(i)-total),2));
        }
        deviation /= name.size();

        deviation = deviation*deviation;

        return (float) deviation;
    }

    public void bubbleSort(int[] array) {
        int temp;
        this.incrementInstructionCounter();
        this.incrementInstructionCounter();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            this.incrementInstructionCounter();
            this.incrementInstructionCounter();
            this.incrementInstructionCounter();
            for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
                this.incrementInstructionCounter();
                this.incrementInstructionCounter();
                if (array[i] > array[j]) {
                    this.incrementInstructionCounter();
                    temp = array[i];
                    this.incrementInstructionCounter();
                    array[i] = array[j];
                    this.incrementInstructionCounter();
                    array[j] = temp;
                    this.incrementInstructionCounter();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public void selectionSort(int[] array) {
        int first, temp;
        this.incrementInstructionCounter();
        this.incrementInstructionCounter();
        this.incrementInstructionCounter();
        for (int i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            this.incrementInstructionCounter();
            this.incrementInstructionCounter();
            first = i;
            this.incrementInstructionCounter();
            this.incrementInstructionCounter();
            for (int j = 1; i < i; j++) {
                this.incrementInstructionCounter();
                this.incrementInstructionCounter();
                if (array[j] < array[first]) {
                    this.incrementInstructionCounter();
                    first = j;
                    this.incrementInstructionCounter();
                }
            }
            this.incrementInstructionCounter();
            temp = array[first];
            this.incrementInstructionCounter();
            array[first] = array[i];
            this.incrementInstructionCounter();
            array[i] = temp;
        }

    }

    public void insertionsort(int[] array) {
        int temp;
        this.incrementInstructionCounter();
        this.incrementInstructionCounter();
        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            this.incrementInstructionCounter();
            this.incrementInstructionCounter();
            temp = array[i];
            this.incrementInstructionCounter();
            int j;
            this.incrementInstructionCounter();
            this.incrementInstructionCounter();
            for (j = i - 1; j >= 0 && temp < array[j]; j--) {
                this.incrementInstructionCounter();
                this.incrementInstructionCounter();
                array[j + 1] = array[j];
                this.incrementInstructionCounter();
            }
            array[j + 1] = temp;
            this.incrementInstructionCounter();
        }
    }

    public void mergerSort(int[] array) {
        mergeSort(array);
    }

    public int[] mergeSort(int[] array) {
        if (array.length > 1) {
            this.incrementInstructionCounter();
            int elementsInA1 = array.length / 2;
            this.incrementInstructionCounter();
            this.incrementInstructionCounter();
            int elementsInA2 = elementsInA1;
            this.incrementInstructionCounter();


            if ((array.length % 2) == 1){
                this.incrementInstructionCounter();
                this.incrementInstructionCounter();
                elementsInA2 += 1;
                this.incrementInstructionCounter();
            }
            int arr1[] = new int[elementsInA1];
            this.incrementInstructionCounter();
            int arr2[] = new int[elementsInA2];
            this.incrementInstructionCounter();     
            this.incrementInstructionCounter();
            for (int i = 0; i < elementsInA1; i++) {
                this.incrementInstructionCounter();
                this.incrementInstructionCounter();
                arr1[i] = array[i];
                this.incrementInstructionCounter();
            }
            this.incrementInstructionCounter();
            for (int i = elementsInA1; i < elementsInA1 + elementsInA2; i++){
                this.incrementInstructionCounter();
                this.incrementInstructionCounter();
                arr2[i - elementsInA1] = array[i];
                this.incrementInstructionCounter();
                this.incrementInstructionCounter();
            }
            arr1 = mergeSort(arr1);
            arr2 = mergeSort(arr2);

            int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
            this.incrementInstructionCounter();
            this.incrementInstructionCounter();
            this.incrementInstructionCounter();

            while (arr1.length != j && arr2.length != k) {
                this.incrementInstructionCounter();
                this.incrementInstructionCounter();
                if (arr1[j] < arr2[k]) {
                    this.incrementInstructionCounter();
                    array[i] = arr1[j];
                    this.incrementInstructionCounter();
                    i++;
                    this.incrementInstructionCounter();
                    j++;
                    this.incrementInstructionCounter();
                } else {
                    array[i] = arr2[k];
                    this.incrementInstructionCounter();
                    i++;
                    this.incrementInstructionCounter();
                    k++;
                    this.incrementInstructionCounter();
                }
            }
            while (arr1.length != j) {
                this.incrementInstructionCounter();
                array[i] = arr1[j];
                this.incrementInstructionCounter();
                i++;
                this.incrementInstructionCounter();
                j++;
                this.incrementInstructionCounter();
            }
            while (arr2.length != k) {
                this.incrementInstructionCounter();
                array[i] = arr2[k];
                this.incrementInstructionCounter();
                i++;
                this.incrementInstructionCounter();
                k++;
                this.incrementInstructionCounter();
            }
        }
        return array;
    }

    public void quickSort(int[] array) {
        int low = 0;
        this.incrementInstructionCounter();
        int high = array.length - 1;
        this.incrementInstructionCounter();

        int middle = low + (high - low) / 2;
        this.incrementInstructionCounter();
        int pivot = array[middle];
        this.incrementInstructionCounter();
        int i = low;
        this.incrementInstructionCounter();
        int j = high;
        this.incrementInstructionCounter();

        while (i <= j) {
            this.incrementInstructionCounter();
            while (array[i] < pivot) {
                this.incrementInstructionCounter();
                i++;
                this.incrementInstructionCounter();
            }
            while (array[j] > pivot) {
                this.incrementInstructionCounter();
                j--;
                this.incrementInstructionCounter();
            }
            if (i <= j) {
                this.incrementInstructionCounter();
                int temp = array[i];
                this.incrementInstructionCounter();
                array[i] = array[j];
                this.incrementInstructionCounter();
                array[j] = temp;
                this.incrementInstructionCounter();
                i++;
                this.incrementInstructionCounter();
                j--;
                this.incrementInstructionCounter();
            }
        }
    }

    public void randomizedQuickSort(int[] array) {
        int low = 0;
        this.incrementInstructionCounter();
        int high = array.length - 1;
        this.incrementInstructionCounter();

        Random r = new Random();
        this.incrementInstructionCounter();
        int pivot = array[r.nextInt(array.length)];
        this.incrementInstructionCounter();
        int i = low;
        this.incrementInstructionCounter();
        int j = high;
        this.incrementInstructionCounter();

        while (i <= j) {
            this.incrementInstructionCounter();
            while (array[i] < pivot) {
                this.incrementInstructionCounter();
                i++;
                this.incrementInstructionCounter();
            }
            while (array[j] > pivot) {
                this.incrementInstructionCounter();
                j--;
                this.incrementInstructionCounter();
            }
            if (i <= j) {
                this.incrementInstructionCounter();
                int temp = array[i];
                this.incrementInstructionCounter();
                array[i] = array[j];
                this.incrementInstructionCounter();
                array[j] = temp;
                this.incrementInstructionCounter();
                i++;
                this.incrementInstructionCounter();
                j--;
                this.incrementInstructionCounter();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no way we could possibly know. Post more information!

Comment: Post some of your code.... then we might be able to help

Comment: All i can infer from your code is that t c.instructionCounter == -1

Comment: Alright I added code.

Comment: You're not using `indexOf` rather than `get` are you?

Comment: No. I am getting the instructioncounter to add to the arraylist.

Comment: I can see your code. You are using `indexOf`.

Comment: Than I am confused. What is the difference of indexof from lets say array[i]

Comment: It's the exact opposite. The equivalent of array[i] for lists is list.get(i). list.indexOf(i) tries to find the number `i` in the list and gives you -1 if it's not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `indexOf` when you mean `get`. `arrayList.indexOf(5)` is the position of the number `5` in the list, or `-1` if it's not there. `arrayList.get(5)` is the number at index 5.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure you are inserting -1 in the `ArrayList`. You should log the value before inserting to see where the -1 is affected to your counter.

Here is a little example using [ArrayList](http://runnable.com/me/VScoioO2CM83NZ-H)

Comment: I'm not I've checked that the number is a number like 62435 but it still ends up as -1 when I print it out.

Comment: The good [link] (http://www.runnable.com/VScq3aLeanE_STHR/arraylist-with-counter-for-java)

Comment: I know how to add to an arraylist I was wondering what could have gone that it would show as -1

Comment: could you provide the full class? i'm sure the sort affecting the value

Comment: pbabcdefp is right you are using indexOf instead of get